# How do I remove the offset from an item with no width in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a div with no width (it is given a width when needed but otherwise should be out of the flow). It has a sibling div with a padding of 10px. That padding is producing an offset for the first div, somehow putting it into the flow even though it has no width or padding itself.

[image: Computed layout of no-width div]

This is only a problem in IE, and I want to keep the padding on the second div. How can I accomplish this?

Here is a Code Pen showing the problem: http://codepen.io/justindaniel/pen/wMxXeW

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second">hi</div>
</div>


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 75%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  border: none;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-grow: initial;
  width: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.first,
.second {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  }

.first {
  flex-basis: 0%;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  border: none;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-grow: initial;
  width: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should add your MARKUP and CSS and then show some effort. SOF is not a free coding serivce

Comment: What IE shows for "Offset" is actually the calculated position of the element. If you add something before it, it will have a different "Offset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a known issue with IE 10-11.

https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box